# WPF drag drop between controls

Tags: wpf

**Caveat:**  My WPF has been piecemealed together.

**Question:**  How can I identify the object dragged from one TreeView and dropped in another?

**Background:**  I've got two treeviews that I'm prototyping to drag and drop between.  Upon drop I want to do something like draw a line from the source to the target, but I'm not seeing a way to find out what the source was.

At the moment, it seems like the source may have to "register" itself on MouseDown then have the DragDrop go to this registration point, e.g. form level property, to get the endpoints.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You may want to have a look at the [Gong Drag and Drop Framework](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)

Comment: Looking into it.  I'm in over my head given what little I know of WPF, but that's all part of the developer game.  Thanks.